# Do NOP sleds expose shellcode?

Tags: exploit, ids, shellcode

I noticed the following sentence on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode#Shellcode_encoding).

> Since intrusion detection can detect signatures of simple shellcodes being sent over the network, it is often encoded, made self-decrypting or polymorphic to avoid detection.

Encoders can camouflage shellcode. However, payloads are often delivered with leading and/or trailing NOP sleds. Could an IDS not simply scan for NOP sleds to detect shellcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDSs will look for nop sleds, but they can also be masked.  Consider that any instruction that is:

- Valid and executable
- Will continue execution somewhere in the nop sled between itself and the payload
- Doesn't affect any critical registers (stack pointer)

Is valid for our purpose.  As long as any sequence of instructions in the sled is a valid starting point (which will end up at our payload), we will have an error-free sled.  If we are okay with it not being 100%, we can be even more creative with our sled.

Check out the nop generators available for metasploit for some ideas on how you can make it, at the very least, expensive for IDS to detect sleds.